# finding value in certain columns only

Tags: excel, vba

Morning,

I am using this code to find a value in a given sheet but I want to add to it so that it only searches columns A to I. I have limited knowledge and every thing I try is coming up with an error. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    Dim value As String
value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).value
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim c As Range
Set ws = Worksheets("Components")
Set c = ws.Cells.Find(value, LookIn:=xlValues)

If Not c Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Parts on the shelf"
c.Delete
Else
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct a range to search in.

`Set c = ws.range("A:I").Find(value, LookIn:=xlValues)`
instead of 
`Set c = ws.Cells.Find(value, LookIn:=xlValues)`
should do the trick.

Here you define the range in which excel will search. Where you searched the entire sheet before by using `Cells`.

Comment: Thank you kindly sir, seems so simple now. I was trying to set the range in the wrong place, lesson learnt :)